# Number of observations needed to distinguish two known distributions with p-confidence

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I have a 1-length cube.   $N$ spots are located in the cube according to the one of known distributions:

- $f(x,y,z) = 1$
- $g(r) = k\ exp(-2\ r^2)$ (where $k$ is a normalization constant and $r= \sqrt{x^2 +y^2+z^2 }$)

**Problem:** How many points, $N$, do I need to distinguish these distributions with $p = 90\%$ confidence?

1. Is it enough to consider not the whole cube, but just a quarter of sphere inside it? (Because it's difficult to transform $f$ to sphere coordinates in cube, but easy in sphere)
2. What exactly is the probability here? Do I have to use statistical tests?

Comment: Do you get to select the locations of your $n$ points, or are they randomly selected from the distributions?  What is $g$?

Comment: @DavidG. I'll edit the question

Comment: Your presentation of $g$ makes no sense.  The argument is always *negative*?  And it is some *arbitrary* function of $r$?  Isn't it possible that your definitions would allow $f = g$ everywhere?  Of course in that case you can *never* distinguish them.

Comment: @David G. Stork my bad, I thought, it was obvious, that r is tadius-vector: r = sqrt(x*x+y*y+z*z)^2. I will edit the question

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Sir, i edited the question. Didnt notice the mistake from the smartphone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, i came up to this solution:

1. Convert  $f(x,y,z)$  to sphere space, using Jacobian, so it is  $f(r,\phi,\theta)$
2. Get rid of $\phi$  and $\theta$ with help of integrating with threshold specific for the cube.
3. Used numeric methods to calculate $E$ and $D$ of each distribution
4. Used statistical test of mean equality, using $E$ and $D$ from previous step